# Solarwinds netflow anaysis not collecting netflow

Tags: hp, monitoring, sflow

I have recently installed the 30 day trial of Orion Network Performance Monitor (solarwinds) and then installed Netflow Traffic Analysis.
I have added our procurve switches and I have used other products to capture sflow and they are able to capture the sflow packets.
I have run wireshark to see what traffic is being passed and there are snmp packets comming in from the switch ip's to the collector but it wont show up any data.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow data is not exported via SNMP. It's exported via whichever port it's configured to export from on the switch (2055 for collecting it via Orion NTA). Do you have your switch configured to export flow data on port 2055 to the ip address of the Orion NTA machine? If so, Orion should see the flow and start capturing it. Most flow collectors that I've used use a "passive" mode of collecting flow data, meaning that you configure the switch to export to the ip and port that the flow collector is at and the flow collector "passively" listens for incoming flows. You don't configure the flow collector for the device, you configure the device for the flow collector.

Comment: I just added the collector to the 2nd sflow destination and configuered polling and sampling and it still has not updated anything on NTA. There is a packet that goes through every now adn then that is sflow in packet wireshark 
227849 1933.538090 10.0.64.12 10.0.65.23 sFlow V5, agent 10.0.64.12, sub-agent ID 0, seq 287, 1 samples

Comment: Got it. I didnt configure the sample rate and polling rate correctly.
Thanks

Comment: YW. Glad to hear you got it working.